# Flutter - Keyboard hiding the screen

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter

i'm making a chat application,the issue is whenever i open the keyboard i can't scroll to the end of the page so the keyboard hide a part of the page
[image]

it hides this part

[image]

```
body: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
            },
            child: ListView(
              children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 190 ,
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  reverse: true,
                  children: [
                    StreamBuilder(
                        stream: StreamFunction(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          return ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              controller: _controller,
                              itemCount: messaging!.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                if (messaging!.isNotEmpty ||
                                    messaging != null) {
                                  if ("${messaging![i]["from"]}" ==
                                      "${snapshot.data}") {
                                    return MyMessage(
                                        "${messaging![i]["message"]}",
                                        "${messaging![i]["timeNow"]}");
                                  } else {
                                    return OtherMessage(
                                        "${messaging![i]["message"]}",
                                        "${messaging![i]["timeNow"]}");
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  return Container();
                                }
                              });
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
             
            ])),
             Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:10, left:10),
                height : 50,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          ),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          maxLines: null,
                          controller: msg,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Write message...",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      FloatingActionButton(
                        mini: true,
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (msg.text.isNotEmpty) {
                            sendMsg(msg.text, '$friendName');
                            msg.clear();
                          }
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.send,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 18,
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                        elevation: 0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ],
    )
```

so as code above it's a listview inside a Stack, i can't scroll inside the listview i used shrikwrap i tried to wrap Stack inside a column but it gets me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the stack is hidden behind the keyboard, use this kind of tree instead:

. Column

.. Expand

... listview

. Send message widget (that will appear in the bottom

Comment: i will not modify your answer but instead of using expanded use flexible

Answer (score 2):

Use scaffold property "resizeToAvoidBottomInset"

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    body: "your Widget",
)
```

Comment: it still not working